# PHPunit Drupal8 : The "node" entity type does not exist

Tags: php, drupal, phpunit, drupal-8

After generating a module with drupal:

```
vendor/bin/drupal generate:module
```

i tried to run unit test in my new module in this file: modules/custom/candidacy_analyser/tests/src/Functional/LoadTest.php

so i used this command after creating phpunit.xml and placed it in core

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration core  modules/custom/candidacy_analyser/tests/src/Functional/LoadTest.php
```

but i found thid Error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) Drupal\Tests\candidacy_analyser\Functional\LoadTest::testLoad
>   Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "node"
>   entity type does not exist.

Stacktrace:

> /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php:133
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityManager.php:54
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/Plugin/Field/FieldType/EntityReferenceItem.php:117
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/BaseFieldDefinition.php:713
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/BaseFieldDefinition.php:736
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/DefaultTableMapping.php:388
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php:696
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php:309
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:1397
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:1483
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:1398
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeListener.php:71
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityManager.php:534
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityDefinitionUpdateManager.php:157
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php:239
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php:83
>   /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Test/FunctionalTestSetupTrait.php:414
>   /var/www/html/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:572
>   /var/www/html/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:398
>   /var/www/html/modules/custom/candidacy_analyser/tests/src/Functional/LoadTest.php:33

the generated file : LoadTest.php :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\candidacy_analyser\Functional;

use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase;

/**
 * Simple test to ensure that main page loads with module enabled.
 *
 * @group candidacy_analyser
 */
class LoadTest extends BrowserTestBase {

  /**
   * Modules to enable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = ['candidacy_analyser'];

  /**
   * A user with permission to administer site configuration.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\user\UserInterface
   */
  protected $user;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->user = $this->drupalCreateUser(['administer site configuration']);
    $this->drupalLogin($this->user);
  }

  /**
   * Tests that the home page loads with a 200 response.
   */
  public function testLoad() {
    $this->drupalGet(Url::fromRoute('<front>'));
    $this->assertSession()->statusCodeEquals(200);
  }

}
```

Any help please ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: no, what is your module name?

Comment: My issue seems to be unrelated.  I'm using the field module, and defined `$this->installEntitySchema('field');` in my `setup()` function, but got the error `The "field" entity type does not exist`.  Once I removed the `installEntitySchema('field')` call then that issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `node` as one of your $modules:

```
public static $modules = ['node', 'candidacy_analyser'];
```

You may also need to include this within `setup()`:

```
$this->installEntitySchema('node');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using drupal 10 what I did is I added the node as a dependency in the .info.yml file related to my module.

```
...
core_version_requirement: ^10
version: 0.0.0
dependencies:
 - drupal:node
```